# Print statement in if branch not firing

Tags: python

The `print()` statement on the last line isn't working, and I'm unsure why.

```py
import random
List=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Number=print(random.choice(List))
if Number == [3,4,6,8]:
    print("Random Number Generator")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `print()` returns `None`. It does *not* return its argument. Don't assign the return value of `print()` to a variable.
2. `Number` is probably meant to be an integer, not a list. Since the types of the variables would be different, this condition will never be true. You want `if Number in [3, 4, 6, 8]:` instead.

Here's a code snippet fixing both issues:

```py
import random
List=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Number=random.choice(List)
print(Number)
if Number in [3,4,6,8]:
    print("Random Number Generator")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm a beginner.